# How to use ImageTexture with Blender 2.8

Tags: texturing, materials

I assigned a material to the character's hair and assigned an ImageTexure.
However, the texture is not displayed and the hair becomes black.
How can this be solved?

[image]

This is the UV used for hair.
[image]

This is the texture.
[image]
[image]

Comment: What are the texture and UV map you were using for? It seems like a hold up area, there must be something disconnect from input

Comment: It's OK for bad English, me too. But please use [edit] to put your texture screenshot and the UV coordinates map. It is hard to figure out what can be the issue from the little properties panel only.  
問題の原因が曖昧のため、texture や UV coordinates mapを [edit] でアップロードしてください。

Comment: Your material and UV maps look okay from what I can see. Textures are working for the other meshes, so your viewport settings are okay. Maybe post your blend (with packed textures) so we can take a look? You could delete everything except the hair if you want don't want to publish your whole model. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: This might be a relative one: [*Why are objects rendering black even with texture (both cycles and BI)?*](/questions/10611/why-are-objects-rendering-black-even-with-texture-both-cycles-and-bi)

Comment: I tried variously but it did not go well. And when I tried to upload the file to blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com, I could not upload it because of an error.

Answer (score 2):

*Reflected* is worked with `Specular` or `Roughness` or `Clearcoat` attributes in principle BSDF. The image texture you assigned is for based color only.

[image]

You can use another image texture to tell that hair should be Reflected by changing those attributes.

Comment: I'm sorry, my English was not good.
I wanted to use "Reflected" in the sense of "displayed".
It is my trouble that the texture of BaseColor is not displayed on the viewport.